# StripeInvalidRequestError: You cannot use `line_items.amount`, `line_items.currency`, `line_items.name`, `line_items.description`, or `line_items

Tags: javascript, next.js, stripe-payments

I'm building an Amazon clone and I'm getting the following error when I try to integrate stripe with the clone. Can someone please help me?
The video I'm referring to is this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4E0WOUYF-QI&t=4092s

The error snippet:

> error - StripeInvalidRequestError: You cannot use `line_items.amount`,
> `line_items.currency`, `line_items.name`, `line_items.description`, or
> `line_items.images` in this API version. Please use `line_items.price`
> or `line_items.price_data`. Please see
> https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migrating-prices for more
> information.

The code snippet:

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async (req, res) => {
    const { items, email } = req.body;

    const transformedItems = items.map((item) => ({
        description: item.description,
        quantity: 1,
        price_data: {
            currency: "gbp",
            unit_amount: item.price * 100,
            product_data: {
                name: item.title,
                images: [item.image],
            },
        },
    }));

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        shipping_rates: ["shr_1LkVMHSArY9HEMGlxjejfRWf"],
        shipping_address_collection: {
            allowed_countries: ["GB", "US", "CA"],
        },
        line_items: transformedItems,
        mode: "payment",
        success_url: `${process.env.HOST}/success`,
        cancel_url: `${process.env.HOST}/checkout`,
        metadata: {
            email,
            images: JSON.stringify(items.map((item) => item.image)),
        },
    });

    res.status(200).json({ id: session.id });
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is with the `transformedItems` function. The API version which you've initialized stripe with, requires the product's description (i.e. `item.description`) to be inside the `product_data` object.

Rewriting your function by simply moving the description inside the object described would simply be:

```js
const transformedItems = items.map((item) => ({
    quantity: 1,
    price_data: {
        currency: "gbp",
        unit_amount: item.price * 100,
        product_data: {
            name: item.title,
            description: item.description, //description here
            images: [item.image],
        },
    },
}));
```

This information was presented in the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migrating-prices) link that the error provided you, but you've probably missed it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const transformedItems = items.map((item) => ({
    quantity: 1,
    price_data: {
      currency: "inr",
      unit_amount: item.price * 100,
      product_data: {
        description: item.description,
        name: item.title,
        images: [item.image],
      },
    },
  }));
```

Comment: The code formatting in this answer isn't clear at all. It looks like you have the same snippet repeated twice, with one copy nested inside the other. I've deleted the extra copy. If this is not what you intended, please edit the answer yourself and try to format it correctly. You can refer to the [formatting guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361).