# Facing Error with Stripe on Create session

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm building an app with NODEJS and Express while I'm integrate with stripe but facing this type of error

Here is my code:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    success_url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/`,
    cancel_url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/tour/${tour.slug}`,
    customer_email: req.user.email,
    client_reference_id: req.params.tourId,
    line_items: [
      {
        name: `${tour.name} Tour`,
        description: tour.summary,
        images: [`https://www.natours.dev/img/tours/${tour.imageCover}`],
        amount: tour.price * 100,
        currency: 'usd',
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
```

Error: You cannot use `line_items.amount`, `line_items.currency`, `line_items.name`, `line_items.de` line_items.images`in this API version. Please use`line_items.price`or`line_items.price_data`.

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73836741/3592771), it might be the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [v2022-08-01](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-08-01), the  following parameters have been removed from create Checkout Session:

- line_items[amount]
- line_items[currency]
- line_items[name]
- line_items[description]
- line_items[images]

You can use the price and price_data parameters instead.

Example

```
const checkout_session = stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  success_url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/`,
  cancel_url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/tour/${tour.slug}`,
  customer_email: req.user.email,
    client_reference_id: req.params.tourId,
    payment_method_types:["card"],
    mode:"payment",
    line_items:[
        {
            "price_data": {
            "currency" : "usd",
            "unit_amount" : tour.price * 100,
            "product_data" : {
                  "name" : `${tour.name} Tour`,
                  "description" : tour.summary,
                   "images" : [`https://www.natours.dev/img/tours/${tour.imageCover}`],
              }
            },
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ]}
  );
```